# Putting a wildcard/regex expression in node/label restriction in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In job configuration, there is a checkbox "Restrict where this project can be run". If you select it, there is an input field about Label Expression.
Is there a way to insert of regex there, and not the exact name?
If yes, could you provide an example of this?
The whole concept behind this, is that I want to assign restrict jobs to slaves that are created automatically, with similar names

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe that field can handle regular expressions, but you don't have to specify the **name** of the slave; you can specify a **label** associated with the slave.

When you create the slave, assign a label (or labels) to it.  Assign the same label to all of the slaves that are suitable for that job.  In the job, restrict it to run only on that label.  A slave that has label can run that job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jason. However, I am creating nodes in AWS, in an automatic way. So the names/labels are like bla-bla_uniqueID.
That's why I needed a regex, in order to throw away the uniqueID

Comment: @gandalf_the_cool - a slave can have **multiple** labels.  So you can have one be the unique ID.  And another one that is the label the jobs will target.