# On a Jenkins Pipeline how to specify an agents containing 'some text' in there name

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to have Jenkins pipline job run only using specific agents. For reasons I can not use **any** and I would prefer not to only use one agent via a label. The agents are named like: abc-a, abc-b, abc-c, xyz-a, xyz-b, xyz-c.

I would like only run the job using agents that are contain abc in their name. I was looking for something like:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        contains: 'abc'
    }
    stages {
        stage ("Example") {
            steps{
                sh 'really cool bash'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I read though the documentation here [Jenkins Pipline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) but the best thing I can find is using a label, but I could be over looking something. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36281909/putting-a-wildcard-regex-expression-in-node-label-restriction-in-jenkins it has been discussed here

Comment: Good find, thank you